# Resize UICollectionViewCells to always fill UICollectionView

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which scrolls horizontally, with UICollectionViewCells that are as tall as the collection view itself and a third as wide (so three at a time fit). The collection view is paged and uses the default Flow Layout.

The cells come from a .xib file and use Auto Layout to keep contents in place.

What I am trying to do is to have the height of the collection view switch between two predefined heights and have the height of the cells always fill the available space, even during the animation.

The collection view animation is done by animating the top constraint to its superview like this, and seems to work:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.collectionViewTopConstraint.constant = (self.collectionViewTopConstraint.constant == 50 ? 100 : 50)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

This however leaves the cells untouched.

I have tried adding the following at the end of the animation block:

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in

}, completion: nil)
```

This almost works but the cells crossfade from one height to another instead of just changing in height, which looks bad.

I have also tried the following:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

This achieves the same effect, but is not as smooth.

Also, in both cases, if the switching animation is called repeatedly, I get this warning:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

I have done loads of research but everything I find involves custom layouts or switching between different layouts which I believe does not apply to me, because even if the height of the collection view is changing, the layout uses the same logic to position elements.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished by changing the itemSize of the cells just before the animation. The original size of the cells was set to the same value as shown below, but without the +sign*50 term.

```
- (IBAction)toggleCollectionViewSize:(id)sender {
    self.collectionViewTopConstraint.constant = (self.collectionViewTopConstraint.constant == 50)? 100 : 50;
    NSInteger sign = (self.collectionViewTopConstraint.constant == 50)? 1 : -1;
    self.layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width/3.0 , self.collectionView.frame.size.height + sign*50);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

I tested this on a cell that had views at the top, middle, and bottom. It looked pretty good, but there was a slight movement of the bottom view that I can't explain. You still do get a slight fading of the cell (its alpha value gets lowered) as the transition occurs. This visual effect can be minimized if the collection view background color is the same as the cell background color.

**After Edit:**

It works better if you use a timer instead of animateWithDuration; I don't get any fading that way.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width/3.0 , self.collectionView.bounds.size.height - 1); // the -1 suppresses a warning about the height that you get on every toggle. I still get one warning at the start.
}


- (IBAction)toggleCollectionViewSize:(id)sender {
    NSInteger sign = (self.topCon.constant == 50)? 1 : -1;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(shrink:) userInfo:@(sign) repeats:YES];
}


-(void)shrink:(NSTimer *) aTimer {
    NSInteger sign = [aTimer.userInfo integerValue];
    self.topCon.constant += sign;
    if (self.topCon.constant == 100 || self.topCon.constant == 50) {
        [aTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does indeed work however as you say its not perfect because fading is still present. I wonder if using a custom Layout changes this. I think I read somewhere that fading is something specific to the Flow layout...

Comment: @LorTush, I think I found a better way using a timer.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. I will also mark it as a correct answer because I think that it is the best we can do without using custom Layouts.

Comment: after height animation complete, you can call collectionView.reload().